# Substring from underscore and onwards in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, instr

I have a string with under score and some characters. I need to apply substring and get values to the left excluding underscore. So I applied below formula and its working correctly for those strings which have underscore (_). But for strings without (_) it is bringing NULL. Any suggestions how this can be handled in the substring itself.

Ex: ABC_BASL ---> Works correctly; ABC ---> gives null

My formula as below -

```
select SUBSTR('ABC_BAS',1,INSTR('ABC_BAS','_')-1) from dual;
ABC

select SUBSTR('ABC',1,INSTR('ABC','_')-1) from dual;
(NULL)
```

Comment: `NULL` seems correct according to your description.  What do you want?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `CASE` expression to first check for an underscore:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'ABC_BAS' AS col FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC' FROM dual
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN col LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
         THEN SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '_') - 1)
         ELSE col END AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: You need to escape the wildcard underscore for `like` - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=327c07e5646e331684e6254026e38917) (and your CTE is missing `union all` *8-).

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression matching:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC_BAS', '(.*)([_]|$)?', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM DUAL;
```

returns 'ABC', and

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC', '(.*)([_]|$)?', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM DUAL;
```

also returns 'ABC'.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0700dae6ee7dbf9d3fff3fb68efa8bfa)

### EDIT

The above gives correct results, but I missed the easiest possible regular expression to do the job:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC_BAS', '[^_]*') FROM DUAL;
```

returns `'ABC'`, as does

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC', '[^_]*') FROM DUAL;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad2ce53fb9a2aa601cd4245214e98ffa)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach is to use the `DECODE` in the length parameter of the `substr` as follows:

```
substr(str, 
       1, 
       decode(instr(str,'_'), 0, lenght(str), instr(str,'_') - 1)
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want everything up to the first `'_'`.  If so, one method uses`regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '(^[^_]+)_.*$', '\1')
from (select 'ABC' as str from dual union all
      select 'ABC_BAS' from dual
     ) s
```

A simpler method is:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '^[^_]+')
from (select 'ABC' as str from dual union all
      select 'ABC_BAS' from dual
     ) s
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c96f85dacbdaaf2a2a9bffc0b066aae) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
regexp_replace(text,'_.*')
```

or if performance was a concern,

```
substr(text, 1, instr(text||'_', '_') -1)
```

For example,

```
with demo(text) as
   ( select column_value
     from   table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('ABC', 'ABC_DEF', 'ABC_DEF_GHI')) )
select text
     , regexp_replace(text,'_.*')
     , substr(text, 1, instr(text||'_', '_') -1)
from   demo;
    
TEXT         REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXT,'_.*') SUBSTR(TEXT,1,INSTR(TEXT||'_','_')-1)
------------ --------------------------- -------------------------------------
ABC          ABC                         ABC
ABC_DEF      ABC                         ABC
ABC_DEF_GHI  ABC                         ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i got it. Add nvl to the substring and insert the condition as below -

```
select nvl(substr('ABC',1,instr('F4001Z','_')-1),'ABC') from dual;
```